# Implementing Entity Framework Relational Division

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relational-division

I have a relational division problem that I am trying to solve in Entity Framework.

I have 2 tables; Stuff and Things.
Each Stuff can have many Things.

The only DbSet that I have to work with is a normalised view of Stuff and Thing containing the ThingId and related StuffId.

I am querying the Things view on a set of conditions and then need to select the Things where all of the Things for the related Stuff exist in the result set. I.e. if any Things are missing for a Stuff after the Where condition is applied then remove all Things related to that Stuff.

I have produced as query that seems to work, but runs way too slow and generally hits a SQL timeout. I need it to run quickly.

Here is my example:

```
public IQueryable<Thing> GetCompleteThingsWhere
                                  (Expression<Func<BetSelection, bool>> conditions)
{
    var filteredThings = this._dbContext.GetQuery<Thing>().Where(conditions);

    var allThings = this._dbContext.GetQuery<Thing>();

    var allThingsForFilteredThings =
        allThings.Where(x => filteredThings.Any(y => y.StuffId == x.StuffId));

    var missingThingsFromFilteredThings =
        allThingsForFilteredThings.Where(x => filteredThings
                                               .All(y => y.ThingId != x.ThingId));

    var completeStuffThings =
        filteredThings.Where(x => !missingThingsFromFilteredThings
                                     .Any(y => x.StuffId == y.StuffId));

    return completeStuffThings;
}
```

The query is taking around 6 minutes to run and the SQL looks very inefficient, executing the original WHERE condition in sub queries in the WHERE clause.

**Further explanation:**

Sample data of Stuff and Things

```
 STUFF            THING
__________       ____________________
| StuffId |      | ThingId | StuffId |
|1        |      |1        |1        |
|2        |      |2        |1        |
|         |      |3        |1        |
|         |      |4        |2        |
|         |      |5        |2        |
|         |      |6        |2        |
```

Lets say the conditions parameter filters the set of Things so that we have i our results set:

```
Results
____________________
| ThingId | StuffId |
|1        |1        |
|4        |2        |
|5        |2        |
|6        |2        |
```

2 of the things related to StuffId 1 are not present in the results set, so now I want to remove all things for StuffId 1 from the results set, leaving only complete Stuff

```
Results
____________________
| ThingId | StuffId |
|4        |2        |
|5        |2        |
|6        |2        |
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It is really hard to understand. Can you give more precise example? What is the prupose of this line `var allThingsForFilteredThings =
        allThings.Where(x => filteredThings.Any(y => y.StuffId == x.StuffId));`? Won't it give you all the filtered things?

Comment: Do your tables have the correct indexes for these queries?

Comment: @mxmissile yes they do

Answer (score 0):

I managed to reduce the query execution time from 6 minutes to under a second by breaking the query up into smaller queries so that the conditions query is executed first and only once, providing a set of Ids to work with when carrying out the relational division rather than letting EF generate subqueries.

```
public IQueryable<Thing> GetCompleteThingsWhere
                              (Expression<Func<BetSelection, bool>> conditions)
{
    var filteredThings = base.Filter(conjunction)
                           .Select(thing => new { thing.StuffId, thing.ThingId})
                           .ToArray();

    var filteredThingsStuffIds = filteredThings
                                    .Select(arg => arg.StuffId)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToArray();
    var filteredThingsThingIds = filteredThings
                                    .Select(arg => arg.ThingId)
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToArray();

    var allThings = this.GetAll();

    var allThingsForFilteredBets =
        allThings.Where(x => filteredThingsStuffIds.Contains(x.StuffId));

    var missingThingsFromFilteredThingsStuffIds =
        allThingsForFilteredBets.Where(x => !filteredThingsThingIds.Contains(x.ThingId))
                                .Select(thing => thing.StuffId)
                                .ToArray();

    var completeBets =
        allThingsForFilteredBets
               .Where(x => !missingThingsFromFilteredThingsStuffIds.Contains(x.StuffId));

    return completeBets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you, you want all the Things belonging to Stuff where all that Stuff's Things match some conditions?

```
public IQueryable<Thing> GetCompleteThingsWhere
                              (Expression<Func<BetSelection, bool>> conditions)
{
    return this._dbContext.GetQuery<Stuff>().Where(e => e.Things.All(conditions))
                                            .Select(e => e.Things);
}
```

---

For working with a normalized StuffThing (see comments):

```
public IQueryable<Thing> GetCompleteThingsWhere
                              (Expression<Func<BetSelection, bool>> conditions)
{
    return this._dbContext.GetQuery<StuffThing>()
                          .GroupBy(e => e.StuffId) // Denormalize
                          .Where(g => g.All(conditions))
                          .SelectMany(g => g);
}
```

Comment: After reading your answer I have just realised that I didn't explain it properly.. Although there are tables Thing and Stuff, the only EF model class that I have to query on is a normalised view that combines data from the two entities. Your answer would make sense if I did have the denormalised model to work with. Thanks!

Comment: @GlenThomas So to make things clearer, you have a "StuffThing" entity that has properties from both Stuff and Thing?

Comment: That looks like it would probably work! I'll give it a test on Monday